# Mootools and three.js conflict

Tags: mootools, three.js

Does anyone have any experience using mootools alongside three.js? Right now it seems to conflict as mootools seems to remove animation, mouse functionality and more from my three.js project.

I used jQuery initially without any problems, but have since converted it to plain javascript. However now I have to make sure that the code is Mootools compatible. The only thing I do is to include the mootool (1.4.5) library, but that is enough to create some conflict.

So does anyone have any experience with mootools and three.js not playing well together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They *shouldn't* affect each other given that all the Three.js stuff is in the THREE namespace. How are you initializing your app? You might want to use MooTools' domready event rather than explicitly setting document onload, if that's what you're doing.

Comment: Keep in mind Mootools is prototypical - which is fine as long as you don't do stupid shit like `for (var i in ['somearray'])` as that will try to iterate expandos from the Array proto - or if you do, check via `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Turnes out that the conflict was due to updating the camera controls in three.js before running the <code>requestAnimationFrame()</code> For some reason this conflicted when including mootools, but doesn't cause any trouble when mootools isn't included.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff it seems Three.js is doing just that in the THREE.EventTarget class (eventtarget.js)